# Skipping a number in a for loop sequence?

Tags: java

so I have another homework question. First, I'll list the instructions and then I'll list my code and hopefully someone can help me/guide me in the right direction.

DIRECTIONS:

**Write a program that calculates the occupancy rate for a hotel.  The program should start by asking the user how many floors the hotel has.  A for loop should then iterate once for each floor.  In each iteration of the for loop, the program should ask the user for the number of rooms of the floor and how many of them are occupied.  After all of the iterations are complete the program should display how many rooms the hotel has, how many of them are occupied, and the percentage of rooms that are occupied.**

> **It is traditional that many hotels do not have a 13th floor.  The for loop in >this program should skip the entire thirteenth loop iteration.**

**Input validation (remember to use a loop never ever an "if"):  Do not accept a value of less than one for the number of floors.  Do not accept a value of less than 10 for the number of rooms on a floor.**

MY CODE:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public class Homework7Hotel
    {
    public static void main (String[] args)
      {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("%#,##0.00");
      int numFloors = 0;
      int numRooms = 0;
      int totalRooms = 0;
      int numOccupied = 0;
      int totalOccupied = 0;
      int percentOccupied = 0;

  System.out.println("Please enter the number of floors in the hotel: ");
  numFloors = keyboard.nextInt();

  while (numFloors <1)
     {
     System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of floors. ");
     System.out.println("Please enter the number of floors in the hotel: ");
     numFloors = keyboard.nextInt();
     }

  for (int counter = 1; counter <=numFloors; counter++)
  {
     System.out.println("Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: " + counter);
     numRooms=keyboard.nextInt();
     totalRooms += numRooms;

  while (numRooms <10)
     {
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of rooms. ");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: " + counter);
        numRooms = keyboard.nextInt();
     }
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of occupied rooms on floor #: " + counter);
        numOccupied = keyboard.nextInt();
        totalOccupied += numOccupied; 
        // *not sure of how to do this* percentOccupied = totalOccupied/totalRooms;    
  }

  System.out.println("The hotel has a total of " + totalRooms + " rooms.");
  System.out.println(totalOccupied + " of the rooms are occupied.");
  System.out.println (percentOccupied + "% of the rooms are occupied.");

   }
}
```

So, the issue I am having is:

1) As per the instructions, how would I skip the 13th floor entirely in the loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I only gave an answer to the 1st part as you are allowed only one per question i guess

Comment: I actually erased the second part because I thought I had it figured out, but I'm having issues with that as well. The second question was, how do I divide two numbers and have them round up if applicable? For example, 71/90 is 78.888888889%. My output shows as 78%, but I need it to be 79%

Comment: Use `Math.round(your_value)` to round off your double value

Comment: _"remember to use a loop **never ever** an "if" "_ So no if statements in the entire program? Or is that just a reminder for you to use loops for your Input validation?

Comment: Hey Abbas, I tried what you suggested and I'm still getting 78% as my output instead of the required 79%.

    percentOccupied = Math.round(totalOccupied*100)/totalRooms;    

is what I am using

Comment: Gulllie, that's only for the input validation. My professor doesn't want us using ifs for input validation. 

"        You CAN use NESTED while/do-while loops.  In parts of this program you will want to have while loops inside of for loops for example.  HINT:  think input validation.  Remember input validation is ALWAYS done with a loop NEVER with an "if" statement."

Comment: You wanted `Math.round((double)totalOccupied * 100 / totalRooms)` - no point in applying `Math.round` to a whole number.  And `(double)` is needed to stop this from being an integer division.

Comment: Thank you, David Wallace. That did the trick and it makes sense too...if I was doing integer division it would never look past the decimal point so it would never round with consideration to the numbers after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("%#,##0.00");
        int numFloors = 0;
        int numRooms = 0;
        int totalRooms = 0;
        int numOccupied = 0;
        int totalOccupied = 0;
        int percentOccupied = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of floors in the hotel: ");
        numFloors = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (numFloors <1)
        {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of floors. ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of floors in the hotel: ");
            numFloors = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        for (int counter = 1; counter <=numFloors; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: " + counter);
            numRooms=keyboard.nextInt();
            //REMOVE totalRooms += numRooms; from here

            while (numRooms <10)
            {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of rooms. ");
                System.out.println("Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: " + counter);
                numRooms = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            totalRooms += numRooms;  //ADD it here

            System.out.println("Please enter the number of occupied rooms on floor #: " + counter);
            numOccupied = keyboard.nextInt();
            totalOccupied += numOccupied;
            // *not sure of how to do this* percentOccupied = totalOccupied/totalRooms;
        }

        System.out.println("The hotel has a total of " + totalRooms + " rooms.");
        System.out.println(totalOccupied + " of the rooms are occupied.");
        System.out.println (percentOccupied + "% of the rooms are occupied.");
    }
```

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that the loop is useless. You need to reenter the correct value and then add it to the total rooms

Comment: while (numRooms <10)
     {
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of rooms. ");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: " + counter);
        numRooms = keyboard.nextInt();
     }

Comment: totalRooms += numRooms;  goes after that^

Comment: I don't understand why I need to change that? I don't have any issues with getting the correct number of total rooms?

Comment: Is it for better programming etiquette?

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and it results in total rooms equaling zero no matter what numbers I enter.

Comment: You can't accept less than 10 for the number of rooms. This is what the 'while (numRooms <10)' loop is for. But you're adding the potentially incorrect(less than 10) input to totalRooms before asking for the correct/valid input. Whatever the loop does will be useless since numRooms will be overwritten in the next iteration.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and this is what I am getting:

The inputs I used were:
30
24
30
27
30
20


The hotel has a total of 0 rooms.
71 of the rooms are occupied.
9,223,372,036,854,776,000% of the rooms are occupied.

Comment: I'm still confused because if I enter a number less than 10 (let's say 9), my program won't continue and will force me enter a number >=10....

Comment: Please enter the number of floors in the hotel: 

3

Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: 1

2

You have entered an invalid number of rooms. 

Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: 1

2

You have entered an invalid number of rooms. 

Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: 1

2

You have entered an invalid number of rooms. 

Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: 1

2

You have entered an invalid number of rooms. 

Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: 1

2

You have entered an invalid number of rooms.

Comment: _while (numRooms <10)_. _While_ the user enters less then 10 rooms, ask them to enter rooms again.

Comment: Yes, it would keep asking for a new number but there will be nothing done with that number 9 will have already been added

Comment: Now I see what you're saying, Anon. I had to test it out a couple of times. I moved it into: 

START CODE HERE: 

while (numRooms <10)
         {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number of rooms. ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of rooms on floor #: " + counter);
            numRooms = keyboard.nextInt();
            totalRooms += numRooms;
         }

Comment: Yeah, it has to be outside the loop. Glad I could help a fellow newbie out.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I took a look at your edit and that worked! I realize now that having it within the totalRooms += numRooms; INSIDE the { } of my while loop was messing with it. Having it OUTSIDE the while loop worked!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a continue keyword in a forloop like.

```
for(int i = 0;i <20;i++){
    if(i == 13){
        continue;
    }
//Do rest of your steps
}
```

If you donot want to use continue use

```
for(int i = 0;i <20;i++){
        if(i != 13){
            //Do rest of your steps
        }
        //This should also work it will not do anything when loop is at its 13th iteration.
    }
```

Using continue though is better.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand this type of coding. We've never used "continue" in our class (yet). Is there any other possible way?

Comment: @Khovsepa You asked a question.  This is the answer.  This is what `continue` is for.

Comment: Yes, David and I'm thankful for the help, but seeing how we haven't learned that in our class, I can't be using something we haven't learned...

Comment: The first method using continue seems to have worked...I'm just hesitant because it's something we haven't learned (yet) and 1) not sure if we're ok to use it and 2) how would I have figured this out had it not been for help websites such as this?

Comment: I would say that programming is something you dnt learn in school always you have to have that zeal to learn and explore everything cannot be taught the teachers set the mentality

Comment: I try my best to use ingenuity to figure out my mistakes and it usually works, but I'm on a bit of a time crunch with the homework and just trying to get it done, but I 100000% agree with what you are saying. There's no "set" way of writing a program.

Answer (score 1):

Without `continue`, you can try `if() else` block to do the work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    if(i == 13)
    {
       // Do the stuff for 13th floor if any
    }
    else
    {
       // Do the stuff for floors other than 13
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much less readable than just using `!=` and putting the content in the `if` block.

Comment: @DavidWallace Obviously. But as he is a beginner, I thought it is better to tell him specifically what he is doing block wise.

Comment: The best time to teach someone good programming practices is when they are a beginner.